# How many subsets are there of a set consisting of $n$ elements?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I understand that there should be $\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}$ subsets but I don't understand how that expression simplifies to $(1+1)^n$ or $2^n$
Namely, I don't understand this equation: 
$$ \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} = (1+1)^n = 2^n$$
Please explain in detail, thanks!

Comment: You can use the Binomial Theorem, $(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^k$, and then let $x=1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) states that

$$(x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}x^{n-k}y^k$$

for a natural number $n$. Using that equation, from right to left,

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} &= \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}1^{n-k}1^k \\[2 ex]
 &= (1+1)^n \\[2 ex]
 &= 2^n
\end{align}$$

You see that I used the binomial theorem with $x=y=1$ and the fact that $1^m=1$ for any natural number $m$. The binomial theorem itself is proved by mathematical induction, and this special case can be proved this way as well.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I totally missed the fact that you can write $1^m$ and always get $1$. In other words each time I don't see a specific $x^{n-k}y^{k}$ in the binomial theorem just like on the left hand side of the second equation, I can always assume its $1^{n-k}1^k$? I'm very new to this concept so I just want to make sure

Comment: @shoestringfries: In this particular case and some similar cases you can assume that. In some other cases, no. You can always try that trick in a problem involving binomial coefficients to see if it solves that particular problem.

Comment: What is an example of a case that doesn't?

Answer (score 3):

I like the combinatorial argument:

When building a subset, we are choosing among $n$ elements. Each element may either be in the subset, or not in the subset. Thus there are $2^n$ ways to build a subset.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} =\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}\cdot 1^k\cdot 1^{n-k}= (1+1)^n = 2^n$$